# How to create a layout using flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I'm trying to create the following layout for one of my web projects. What's the best way to create that using HTML, CSS (Flex)?

I'm struggling with bottom-margin for C & D in Desktop screens, for D in Mobile screens.

[image]

Comment: _Show us_ what code you have so far.

Comment: _“I'm struggling with bottom-margin for C & D in Desktop screens, for D in Mobile screens.”_ - specify general `margin-bottom: 30px` for the elements, overwrite inside mobile media query for the `:last-child`, and … done?

Comment: You are supposed to provide a [mcve], not pictures.

Answer (score 3):

As we don't have your code, so based on your question here i provide solution let me know if you have any question..

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
         <div class="card p-5">
            A
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
         <div class="card p-5">
            B
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
         <div class="card p-5">
            C
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
         <div class="card p-5">
            D
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```css
.main_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
}

.sections {
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aqua;
}


/*here for mobiles inside mobile media query put this*/

.main_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="sections">A</div>
  <div class="sections">B</div>
  <div class="sections">C</div>
  <div class="sections">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP needs to use flexbox, not grid :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <p>Write text here A</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <p>Write text here B</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="cs-t20">
   <!-- spacer -->
</div>
</div>  
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <p>Write text here C</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <p>Write text here D</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="cs-t20">
   <!-- spacer -->
</div>
</div>  
<style>
   .cs-t20{
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   }
</style>
```

Hope it will help you!! All the Best !!

Comment: So you need it in pure HTML, CSS?

Comment: I don't need, but I believe OP does :)

Answer (score 0):

```
here your go..
```

```css
.cs-t20 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.continer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.webpage-page-display {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
}

.webpage-page-column {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.webpage-page-half {
  margin-left: 6%;
  width: 47%;
}

.webpage-page-first {
  margin-left: 0px;
  clear: left;
}

.webpage-page-half {
  width: 100%;
}

.webpage-page-column {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .webpage-page_column_table_cell {
    display: block;
  }
  .webpage-page-half {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .webpage-page-column {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="webpage_section">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="webpage-page-column webpage-page_column_table_cell webpage-page-first webpage-page-half webpage-page-display">

      <p>Write text here A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="webpage-page-column webpage-page_column_table_cell webpage-page-half webpage-page-display">
      <p>Write text here B</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cs-t20"></div>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="webpage_section">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="webpage-page-column webpage-page_column_table_cell webpage-page-first webpage-page-half webpage-page-display">

      <p>Write text here C</p>
    </div>
    <div class="webpage-page-column webpage-page_column_table_cell webpage-page-half webpage-page-display">
      <p>Write text here D</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cs-t20"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```